# Type mismatch caused by inner vs external class - why?

Tags: java, android, types, inner-classes

I'm having a very weird problem. I have asked my course mates about it, but they said that they do not know why this is happening.

This is my main class with a method that returns type Fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
//....
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            return new AccelerometerMonitorFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
//...
}
```

Now, if I put class "AccelerometerMonitorFragment" inside my main class as an inner class:

```
public static class AccelerometerMonitorFragment  extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //do something
            return null;
        }

}
```

This will work fine, no errors. But I would like to have it in separate file, for cleanness purposes.

So I create a separate class file, delete the inner class, and try to use it.

```
package com.example.actrecognition;
//imports...
public class AccelerometerMonitorFragment  extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // do something
        return null;
    }

}
```

But then I get this error:
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from AccelerometerMonitorFragment to Fragment

I do not understand it, because the class in the separate file extends Fragment, so what is the problem? Why having the class in external file and not static breaks the code?

Comment: This time, actually provide the imports. Sounds like one Class is using the support Fragment imports while the other is using the regular.

Comment: I trusted CTRL+Shift+O in eclipse too much. Thank you, I feel stupid now.

Comment: Do not feel stupid, just don't blindly trust in the IDE to handle all the dirty work (that we the programmers should do).

Comment: @moa no problem, it's one of the things that you should always watch out for. As as well as declaring your Activity to be a `FragmentActivity` if you are going to be using the support fragments.